# SQL Server: Generic Stored Procedure to move data from one table to another table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-query-store

Here are my requirements:

1. To archive data from one table to another, I am looking for a perfect way. I want to schedule a job and set the parameter like DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName, FilterQuery, etc.
2. Parameter should be the configurable
3. I can achieve this requirement through the Dynamic Query, but my DBA told me to avoid the dynamic query.
4. Is there any way I can achieve the requirement without a dynamic query?

Comment: What you're describing is by definition a dynamic query.

Comment: sorry, but it is another attempt to invent "silver bullet"

Comment: Phrases like "my DBA told me" suggest your team is dysfunctional. Ask WHY! Ask for examples and help and ideas! Your development team should be supporting each other and helping everyone learn and become more knowledgeable. And your DBA is generally wrong - there is nothing dangerous, bad, or evil about properly written dynamic SQL.

Comment: The fact your DBA told you to do this, but told you not to do it with dynamic SQL suggests, with all due respect to them, that they have *no idea* what they are talking about. The requirements they have given conflict; to "parametrise" your object names you *need* to use dynamic SQL. It's like being asked to paint the wall with white paint without using white paint. Plus the fact that a requirement like this is most certainly a sign of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) and that the real probably is very different.

Comment: While @SMor is correct that it's not inherently bad to use dynamic queries; they can become unwieldy quickly when performing complex queries - which is maybe what your DBA was getting at... Unless the DBA just wants you to set up a stored procedure for each table that needs archiving.

Comment: One way to move fast data from one table to another is to use partitionned table and then do a SWITCH PARTITION, that transfer at once rows from the source table to the target table.